# Read Files using a function C++

Tags: c++, io, stream, readfile

I'd like to know how to read a file using streams but also using them inside a function.
So far my code is;:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void burbuja(int[]);
void imprimeArreglo (int[],int);
void leeArchivo(string&);
int arreglo[10];
int i;

void burbuja (int a[])
{
int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            if(a[i]>a[j])
            {
                int temp=a[i]; //swap
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
            }

        }

    }
}
void imprimeArreglo(int a[],int tam)
{
    for(int i=0;i<tam;i++)
    cout << a[i] << " ";
}
void leeArchivo(string& nombre)
{
string filename = nombre;
ifstream myfile(filename);
string line;
if (myfile.is_open()) {
 while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      cout << line << '\n';
    }
    myfile.close();
}
else cout << "Unable to open file"; 


}
int main()
{
    string nombre = "arr.txt";

  leeArchivo(nombre);
      cin >> i ;
      return 0;
}
```

I'd like to be able to call leeArchivo("arr.txt") from the main method. 
With this I get the errors:

```
Error:  bubble.cpp(37,14):'ifstream' is not a member of 'std'
Error:  bubble.cpp(37,19):Statement missing ;
Error:  bubble.cpp(39,20):Undefined symbol 'file'
Error:  bubble.cpp(39,25):Could not find a match for 'std::getline(undefined,std::basic_string<char,std::string_char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>)'
```

What am I missing here? (I'm new to C++)
The file I'm trying to read has the following structure:
`<number>`

`<number> <number> <number> ...`

E.G.:

5

19 28 33 0 1

=========================================

EDIT:
**I'm using Borland C++ 5.02**

EDIT 2:
**Updated code, using Geany** Now error is: `BUBBLE.cpp:38:25: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(std::string&)'`

Comment: 1) your main function has no return type, 2) you `using namespace std;` yet in some place still put `std::` in. Just remove the using directive and specify `std::`, 3) [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream) is definitely a member of namespace `std::`

Comment: That said, what compiler are you using? (I'm surprised it said nothing about main not having a return type)

Comment: Outside of the non-standard declaration of `main()`, [this should compile correctly](http://ideone.com/KDy4mj). Whatever you stripped from the code when posting it, put it back and update the post. While doing so, also add the compiler and platform you're building on. (And I would use `cstdlib` but that shouldn't cause the issue you're experiencing; the code you're *not* showing is responsible for that). The errors reported claim they're on lines 37 and 39. Clearly something is missing.

Comment: Just added the whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's particularly odd behavior with `ifstream`. Try this edit:

```
void leeArchivo(const string&);
void leeArchivo(const string& nombre)
{
    ifstream file(nombre.c_str());
    string line;
    while(getline(file,line)) {
        cout << line << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    leeArchivo("arr.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Also, use:

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

Instead of:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: While trying to use cstdlib I get an error. `Error:  bubble.cpp(2,2):Unable to open include file 'CSTDLIB.h'`

Comment: @DavidMerinos: You're trying `#include <cstdlib.h>`. That doesn't exist. It's supposed to be: `#include <cstdlib>`.

Comment: No, my line is: `#include <cstdlib>`

Comment: Could it be a bug from my Borland C++? @jrd1

Comment: @DavidMerinos I won't say it's a bug per se, but rather that **it's a result of using a horribly, horribly, horribly outdated and obselete non-standard C++ compiler.** Your best bet is to download a decent compiler than conforms to the standard. A good place to start is to use cygwin with gcc/clang: http://www.cygwin.com/ (which is free). Or, if the option is open to you, obtain either the Intel C++ or VC++ compilers (these are proprietary compilers).

Comment: I'm using Geany now. Still getting some errors. Just updated my post

Comment: @DavidMerinos: Use this instead: `leeArchivo(nombre.c_str());` That's because `ifstream` doesn't take `std::string` parameters - it requires `const char *` parameters: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/

Comment: Worry not, I installed GCC libraries and I can Run programs in Geany. It opens Windows Console. So yeah, it's an _small IDE_.